# Error when move older files to new location

Tags: linux

I used below command to move to folder called "old" some log files which are older than 3 days.

```
find -type f -mtime +3 -exec mv {} old/ \;
```

After run this command it moves those files and it gives following errors. Why is that?

```
mv: `./old/catalina.out-20130410.bz2' and `old/catalina.out-20130410.bz2' are the same file
mv: `./old/catalina.out-20130411.bz2' and `old/catalina.out-20130411.bz2' are the same file
mv: `./old/catalina.out-20130412.bz2' and `old/catalina.out-20130412.bz2' are the same file
mv: `./old/catalina.out-20130413.bz2' and `old/catalina.out-20130413.bz2' are the same file
mv: `./old/catalina.out-20130414.bz2' and `old/catalina.out-20130414.bz2' are the same file
mv: `./old/catalina.out-20130415.bz2' and `old/catalina.out-20130415.bz2' are the same file
mv: `./old/catalina.out-20130416.bz2' and `old/catalina.out-20130416.bz2' are the same file
mv: `./old/catalina.out-20130417.bz2' and `old/catalina.out-20130417.bz2' are the same file
```

Answer (score 4):

Is `old` a subdirectory of the working directory?

In that case you need to tell `find` not to descend into the `old` subdirectory using the `-maxdepth 0` option.

Comment: Thanks Macro. It works!   find -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +3 -exec mv {} old/ \;

Comment: @user2143989 if this answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted.